# Is there such a different phase control relay?

Tags: relay, control, three-phase

**PROBLEM**

The standard phase control relay is output from any phase. However, there will be no output when that phase is gone.

**PROPOSAL**

When any phase is gone, the switch of the phase distribution circuit will connect the other phase to the output. The following picture is intended to give an idea.

Is there such a sold phase control relay? Or do I design it myself? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It's a standard product to detect phase loss, but if you want to run a single phase load, but changeover on phase loss then you need to implement that yourself. It's a bit odd to be wanting to continue operation when one of 3 phases fails.

Comment: @JackCreasey , You're totally right, but I don't want to stop a circuit. What I want is to phase out an alarm system in any case.